# Why does this PHP code overwrite file contents while opening?

Tags: php

I've written some pretty complex PHP apps using this feature, so I'm not sure what's happening here.

I'm currently writing an app that uses an online history to save content (via ajax get). The API I wrote to store the user's history to a file is extremely simple:

```
$myFile = "./snhistory/".$_GET["uid"];
$stringData = urldecode($_GET["name"])."\n";
$file = fopen($myFile,"a");
fwrite($file,$stringData);
fclose($file);
```

This looks like the kind of code that adds the data found in `name` plus a new line to the end of a file, right? Well, that's not how PHP sees it. It adds one name, then when I run the code with a different name, it overwrites the first and only the second one appears. I've tried anything I could think of:

```
 file_put_contents($myFile,file_get_contents($myFile).$stringData);
```

And

```
 file_put_contents($myFile,$stringData,FILE_APPEND);
```

And

```
fopen($myFile,"w");
fseek($file,0,SEEK_END);
```

And all produce the same behaviour. Is it something wrong with PHP or am I missing something here? I feel like if there was a problem in the code, the second thing I tried would have fixed it. But I'm not sure, which is why I'm asking everyone here.

I would really appreciate any help that could be provided.

**Edit:** As per the answer, the problem with the strings was that they contained punctuation like `'` and, for some reason, the url encoding and escaping doesn't work. Read the answer's edit for the final answer.

Comment: You aren't passing `$file` to `fwrite` - I assume that's just an error in the question and not the actual code.

Comment: I think after opening the file in append mode you need to `seek` to the end, as the file pointer will be pointing to the start (at least I have seen such behavior in other programs). Combination of the two things you tried... Can't test right now... Thus "comment" rather than answer.

Comment: Yeah. That's a mistake in the question. Let me fix that. Thank you.

Comment: Similarly your `fseek` needs to use `$file` not `$myFile` right?

Comment: Maybe you're doing this in your full code and just haven't shown it in the snippet posted here, but be sure to sanitize `$_GET['uid']` before using it. Someone could send a string like `../../someOtherFile` and manipulate the contents of it.

Comment: `fwrite($stringData)` should be `fwrite($file, $stringData)`

Comment: could it have something to do with permissions?

Comment: @Floris Opening a file with the `a` mode/flag (via php.net): "Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it."

Comment: @OsmiumUSA Are you on Windows, or Linux? If you're using PHP 4.3.10 or greater, you should be using PHP_EOL which is a constant within PHP that holds the line break character (cr, lf, or crlf) depending on the platform/operating system it's running on. There's a chance that could cause the overwrite.

Comment: @DavidScherer - I know that is obviously what is _supposed_ to happen, but as I said, I seem to recall I have observed the "wrong" behavior before although I cannot recall the exact circumstances now. And given OPs observations, it seems that the file is not getting appended, but overwritten... So I thought it might be worth trying.

Comment: Also, how did you install PHP on this machine (Yum, apt, source, Windows installer,...)? Is this the first time you've ran PHP on this machine?

Comment: Just to clarify exactly what is happening: you use the SAME value `_GET["uid"]`, but a DIFFERENT value `_GET["name"]`, and the result is that the first name (file contents) gets overwritten with the second - but it's the same file (you think). What happens if you simply open and close the file without the `fwrite` in between? Is the old content preserved? In other words, is the problem with the `fwrite` or with the `fopen`? What happens if you use a static string for your filename (for debug). What if it's not in a subdirectory?

Comment: If you are using windows operating server, you should use `\r\n` as the line ending character

Comment: beware of potential path injection attacks in `$_GET['uid']`. Make sure it's sanitised. (If it's a numeric ID as implied by the name, you could cast it to integer; that would be sufficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following code on your machine:

```
<?php
$myFile = "./myfile.txt";
$myString="hello world\n";
$fp = fopen($myFile, "a");
fwrite($fp, $myString);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

First time I run it (from command line, with `php app.php`, it creates a file with a single "hello world" line in it.

Run it again, and there are two lines. Again, and there are three...

This is a good test of your basic php installation. If this works, and yet your problem persists, then there's something about the variables you are using that is messing you up - or permissions on the directories, etc. Not a complete solution - but something to help you narrow it down, perhaps?

**EDIT**
Based on the discussions we had in the comments, it seems that this behavior comes and goes depending on the contents of the (URL encoded) variable (`$_GET("name")`), and that the solution is to "cleanse" the variable - get rid of whatever "bad" characters cause this overwriting behavior. I am adding this information to the answer so people don't have to wade through the answer - if you would provide details on what exact string content makes the behavior appear, it would be helpful to the community.

Comment: Same behavior is occurring. As I am not the server administrator, all I can do is show you the `php_info();` of my page if you wish to see that.

Comment: Strange! What is the LENGTH of the file... does it get longer? If so, then it's indeed a problem with the newlines as @gamut is suggesting (although strictly speaking `\n` is "new line" and `\r` is "carriage return".) You could leave the `\n` out and then should definitely see the output...

Comment: Here's an interesting thing I found: if I use the same variable for `name` and run your script (that obviously doesn't even touch the name variable) it works as predicted. However if name is different than the last time, it overwrites the file (confirmed by file size that its not a line ending problem, its actually not appending the data.)

Comment: It gets stranger! So if you use the same variable twice, the file is appended (it gets twice as long after the second time it's run); but if you change it, it doesn't? Does that depend on the contents of `$name`? Can you create a self contained script like mine above (modify mine, including the value of any variables) that reproduces the error? I guess if you had `myString1` and `myString2`, and did two cycles of `open,write,close`, it should reproduce?

Comment: Your code works. So its not the configuration that's the problem. Even feeding it a BS variable (a=1 then a=2) it would work. So the problem may actually lie with the variable contents (`name`, that is). Let me see...

Comment: It turns out that the problem is the variable. Even though its being URL encoded it still is causing issues. It works when `name` is something like a or b. So I'll have to cleanse the input.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include cleansing variables so that people don't have to read the comments, I'll accept your answer because you were so helpful. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @OsmiumUSA : Edit made - if you have an example of a "bad" string, it would be good...

Comment: Added what the problem was on my question. Again, thanks for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed likely the line endings.  When you `type` a text file in windows, if you're been using LF, instead of CRLF, then console output will keep overwriting each line with the next one.  A good way to test this is to open the file in an editor like Notepad++.

Same problem happens on linux if you use \n instead of \r.  Then `cat` will keep outputting to the same line.  So, the problem are your line endings, not your file write commands.